# Firebase functions | Two index.js file?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a supplier app and a customer app both sharing a single Firestore.

The supplier functions requires multiple imports

```
import x from "X";
import y from "Y";
import z from "Z";
```

The customer functions also requires multiple imports but its not same as the supplier imports

```
import a from "A";
import b from "B";
import c from "C";
```

So is its possible to have two index.js file so that when customer makes a request, `import x from "X";` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330778/15774176):

> Doing the expensive require from inside the function body does not
> necessarily lead to slower function calls, as requires are cached
> in-memory. Warm invocations (those that don't require a cold start)
> will run the required line but won't actually need to reload the code.
>
> ```
> // runs at cold start time, use for shared dependencies 
> const commonImport = require("common-import"); 
>
> exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
> // runs only at invocation time but cached, use for unshared deps 
> const expensiveImport = require("expensive-import"); 
> });
> ```
>
> For what it's worth, this particular type of problem is also something
> the Firebase team is actively investigating how to improve. You might
> consider signing up for the [Firebase Alpha Program](https://services.google.cn/fb/forms/firebasealphaprogram/) to receive
> word of early testing for such features.

A workaround also provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71331201/15774176):

> ```
> const common = require("common-import"); 
> if (process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === "fn1") { 
> const expensive1 = require("expensive-import-1"); 
> } 
>  
> if (process.env.FUCNTION_NAME === "fn2") { 
> const expensive2 = require("expensive-import-2"); 
> } 
>  
> exports.fn1 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
> res.send(expensive1.expensiveResult()); 
> }); 
>  
> exports.fn2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
> res.send(expensive2.expensiveResult());
>  });
> ```
>
> This will load only the files you want on cold-start. Those
> environment variables won't be present when we run your code locally
> to discover what functions to deploy, however, so you must always
> export all functions you want to deploy.

For more information about how to manage multiple functions, you can refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions):

> As you integrate Cloud Functions into your project, your code could
> expand to contain many independent functions. You may have too many
> functions to reasonably fit in a single file, or different teams may
> deploy different groups of functions, creating a risk of one team
> overwriting or accidentally deleting another team's functions. Cloud
> Functions offers different ways to organize your code to make it
> easier to navigate and maintain your functions.

Comment: @ibrahimxcool Posted an answer, is it helpful?